# Where to I copy mouse cursor themes in xfce 4.8

Tags: debian, xfce, theme, cursor

I'm running Debian wheezy, xfce 4.8.
Where do I copy mouse cursor themes I downloaded from xfce-look?

If you can give me the location to copy themes, icons, and cursors I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Cursors (4.4 and 4.6)

```
Extract the theme in ~/.icons
    System wide installation in ${sysprefix}/share/icons
Make sure the directory layout looks like this: ./icons/<theme_name>/cursors
Select the theme in the Mouse Settings. If there is no tab with cursor themes, make sure xfce-mcs-plugins (Xfce 4.4.x) is compiled with Xcursor support
```

Link: http://wiki.xfce.org/howto/install_new_themes

Comment: For other n00bs like me, `sysprefix=/usr` at least on Manjaro.

Answer (score 1):

The general location for themes in Debian is `/usr/share/themes`. There are some that can be copied to `~/.themes` but I'm not sure XFCE use it by default.